# Problems Adding Member to Custom Class

Tags: powershell, class

I'm currently building a script with a GUI based on XAML. Because I want my code stay clean I started messing around with classes (i don't even know if this is a good idea) for building the windows.

The basement works pretty good but I have problems constructing the class.

What I'm basically trying to do:

- Building a class for my "window constructor"
- Give some XML to it
- Build Properties (for buttons, textboxes and stuff) based on the XAML
- Of course open the window

At first I had it as a function and this worked very well. But getting more windows to pop up it got a little bit messy, that's why I'm trying to convert this into a class.

First the code (I simplified it to the basic problem):

```
  class OutWindow {
    [XML]$xaml
    [System.Xml.XmlNodeReader]$reader
    [System.Windows.Window]$window

    loadWindow() {
        $this.reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $this.xaml)
        
        try {
            $this.window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $this.reader )
        } catch {
            Write-Warning $_.Exception
            throw
        }

        #GUI ueberpruefen und Variablen Generieren
        $this.xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {
            try {
                ###This is the old line, when it just was a function => worked
                #Set-Variable -Name "var_$($_.Name)" -Value $this.window.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop -Scope Global

                #here I'm trying to the whole thing with class properties
                $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "var_$($_.Name)" -Value $this.window.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop
           } catch {
                throw
            }
        }
    }
}

$hurr = New-Object OutWindow

$hurr.xaml = @"
        <Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="650" Height="700" Name="Window_Properties">
            <Grid>
              <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="650" Margin="5,5,0,0" Name="grid_window" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Check" CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Check}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Eigenschaft" Binding="{Binding Path=Eigenschaft}" CanUserSort="True" Width="*" IsReadOnly="true"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
              </DataGrid>

              <Button Content="Go" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="40" Margin="450,20,0,0" Name="btn_set"/>
            </Grid>
        </Window>
"@

$hurr.loadWindow()
```

Now I'm getting an error on this line:

```
 $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "var_$($_.Name)" -Value $this.window.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop
```

It says:

> Add-Member : Der Wert "System.Windows.Window" vom Typ "System.Windows.Window" kann nicht in den Typ
> "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock" konvertiert werden. In
> Zeile:23 Zeichen:25
>
> - ...     $this | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "var_$($_.Nam ...
> - ```
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Member], PSInvalidCastException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId :  ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCommand

(Can't convert from type "System.Windows.Window" to "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock")

I'm not a programmer and don't have any idea how get this working, and even if it's possible the way I'm thinking.

Can anyone give me a hint, what to do / where to look?

Thanks in advance,
Erratum

Comment: Change `-Value` argument to `{ $this.window.FindName($_.Name) }` - although I have to say, this is _not_ a very clean approach - having to call `Add-Member` with dynamic property names against `$this` in a class definition is sorta defeating the whole purpose of defining a custom type in the first place

Comment: Damn, shame on me for not seeing this one o.O
Thank's @MathiasR.Jessen
(Even if you're right an it's not very elegant)

Comment: Why not just create a `[hashtable]$WindowElements` property for the class and add the XAML entries to that?